# How to indicate the measure when use dimension members as ROWS in mdx query?

Tags: mdx

Here is the query that I am using:

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY { [Dim Date].[Week].[Week].Members } ON COLUMNS,
[Dim Source].[Source Name].[Source Name].Members ON ROWS
FROM [Some Cube];
```

The things is, right now, I have many measures.
But as I am using dimension members on COLUMNS, I cannot indicate the measure anymore.
So this query results in a default measure.

My question is how can I indicate the measure instead of using the default in mdx query?
Or is there any other way that I can do this query (dimension in both row and columns is required for reading result logic in C# in possible) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in two ways:

Either on the SELECT statement, as

```
{ [Dim Date].[Week].[Week].Members } * { [Measures].[My Measure] } ON COLUMNS,
```

or on the WHERE slicer by adding

```
WHERE [Measures].[My Measure]
```

at the end.